# Tesseract not recognizing letter "I"

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use the `--psm 10` option of tesseract to recognize single letters. However, it's having trouble recognizing the letter `I` from this image:

[image: Letter-I]

I'm pre-processing the image to make it black and white so it looks like this:

[image: Black-White-Letter]

However, it still doesn't recognize the correct letter sometimes.

Weirdly enough, it does recognize this `I`:

[image: Other-Letter-I]

I'm running the tesseract using `pytesseract` like this:

```
tess_config = r'--psm 10 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def get_text_from_image(pil_img):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_img, lang='eng', config=tess_config)
    return text
```

The way I'm pre-processing the image is like this:

```
 from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

 def add_padding(pil_img):
     padding = 100
     width, height = pil_img.size
     new_width = width + 2 * padding
     new_height = height + 2 * padding
     result = Image.new(pil_img.mode, (new_width, new_height), '#fff')
     result.paste(pil_img, (padding, padding))
     return result

 img = Image.open(image_url)
 img = img.resize((200, 160))
 thresh = 60
 fn = lambda x: 255 if x > thresh else 0
 black_white_img = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')
 final_img = add_padding(black_white_img)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The font I'm trying to detect is called `Helvetica Neue` if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: if I remove `resize()` and `add_padding()` then `--pms 8` and `--pms 13` recognizes it as `I`. Pytesseract may have problem when text is too small but also when text is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doesn't explain problem but `tesseract` may have problem when text is too small but also when text is too big.

If I remove `resize()` and `add_padding()` then I get `I` for `--psm 8` and `--psm 13`.

---

Original size is `59x79` and `resize((200,160))` gives deformated letter.

If I use `resize((59*2, 79*2))` or `resize((120, 160))` (and add `add_padding()`) then I get `I` for `--psm 7`, `--psm 9`, `--psm 10`

---

My code for test:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import pytesseract

# ---
import sys
import PIL
print('Python:', sys.version)
print('platform:', sys.platform)
print('PIL:', PIL.__version__)
print('pytesseract:', pytesseract.__version__)
print('tesseract:', pytesseract.get_tesseract_version())
print('---')
# ---

def add_padding(pil_img):
    padding = 100
    width, height = pil_img.size
    new_width = width + 2 * padding
    new_height = height + 2 * padding
    result = Image.new(pil_img.mode, (new_width, new_height), '#fff')
    result.paste(pil_img, (padding, padding))
    return result

def get_text_from_image(pil_img, tess_config):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_img, lang='eng', config=tess_config)

filename = 'vT088.png'

img = Image.open(filename)
print('size:', img.size)
#img = img.resize((200, 160))
#img = img.resize((120, 160))
img = img.resize((img.size[0]*2, img.size[1]*2))
print('size:', img.size)
#img.show()

thresh = 60
fn = lambda x: 255 if x > thresh else 0
img = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')
#img.show()

img = add_padding(img)
#img.show()

for x in range(1, 14):
    try:
        text = get_text_from_image(img, f'--psm {x} -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
        text = text.strip()  # remove `new line`
        print(f'psm: {x:2} | {text:1} | {text.encode()}')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
```

Result:

```
Python: 3.10.6 (main, Aug 10 2022, 11:40:04) [GCC 11.3.0]
platform: linux
PIL: 9.2.0
pytesseract: 0.3.10
tesseract: 4.1.1
---
size: (59, 79)
size: (118, 158)
psm:  1 |   | b''
Exception: (1, 'Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.')
psm:  3 |   | b''
psm:  4 |   | b''
psm:  5 |   | b''
psm:  6 |   | b''
psm:  7 | I | b'I'
psm:  8 |   | b''
psm:  9 | I | b'I'
psm: 10 | I | b'I'
psm: 11 |   | b''
psm: 12 |   | b''
psm: 13 |   | b''
```

Comment: So strange, I'm copying your code exactly and still not getting the same results :(

Here's the starting image and the images after the transformations: https://imgur.com/a/aeh3WGs

Comment: I get correct result also for your image from imgur. I added code which displays tesseract version. I have `tesseract 4.1.1`

Comment: Ah. I'm on the latest version: `5.2.0`. Such a weird regression.